# Как изменить редактор коммитов на стандартный?

Tags: git, git-config

Необходимо зменить редактор коммитов на стандартный.

Вот что получается при коммите:

> svaitoslav@svaitoslav-R510-P510:/media/svaitoslav/0E05B44D60917463/Work/test$ git commit
>   error: cannot run sublime_text: No such file or directory
>   error: unable to start editor 'sublime_text'
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option

Каким образом можно изменить редактор для коммитов на дефолтний по системе *ubuntu*? `git config --global core.editor` - не помогло.

Comment: А что Вы называете "стандартным редактором"? для меня это вим. Но может Вам более подходит эмакс.

Comment: Если `git config --global core.editor "vim"` не помогает, значит выставлен редактор локально - перейдите в каталог репозитория и выполните `git config --local core.editor "vim"`.

Comment: @KoVadim, Vim,  только как его назначить ?

Comment: я выше написал.

Comment: @KoVadim к сожалению не помогло , выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: переустановка Vim помогла)

Answer (score 1):

проблема решилась переустановкой редактора vim